# How to sort array of objects by max value through map in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to print value from an API data and currently, I am able to print it alpbhabetically. Now, I would like to print in the order of max values to min values. I would like to show the array data by most number of cases to the least number of cases. But, I am having tough time to figure out how to do this. Here is my code:

[API link](https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries?sort=country)

```
import React from 'react'
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';

const Result = (props) => {
  console.log('props value is:' + props.data)
  let { searchCheck, searchValue } = props;


  let update = props.data.map((item) => {

    const { countryInfo, country, cases, deaths, recovered, active, casesPerOneMillion } = item;
    return (
      (searchCheck) ? country.toUpperCase().includes(searchValue.toUpperCase()) ?
        <tbody>
          <tr key={countryInfo._id}>
            <td><img style={{ height: '25px', width: '50px' }} src={countryInfo.flag} /></td>
            <td>{country}</td>
            <td>{cases}</td>
            <td>{active}</td>
            <td>{recovered}</td>
            <th>{casesPerOneMillion}</th>
            <td>{deaths}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody> :
        '' :
        <tbody>
          <tr key={countryInfo._id}>
            <td><img style={{ height: '25px', width: '50px' }} src={countryInfo.flag} /></td>
            <td>{country}</td>
            <td>{cases}</td>
            <td>{active}</td>
            <td>{recovered}</td>
            <th>{casesPerOneMillion}</th>
            <td>{deaths}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th>Flag</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Cases</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th>Recovered</th>
            <th>Cases per one Million</th>
            <th>Deaths</th>


          </tr>
        </thead>
        {update}
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Result;
```

Comment: Need data structure

Comment: It's coming from here: https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries?sort=country

Comment: Is there even an attempt to sort something in that code?

Comment: `const [sortedData, setSortedData] = React.useState(props.data.slice().sort((a,b) => b.cases - a.cases));` I don't know any efficient method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it like:

```
var sortedData = [...data].sort((a, b) => b.cases - a.cases)
```

here, `data` actually is `props.data` that you are using.

DEMO:

```js
(async() => {
  let response = await fetch('https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries?sort=country');
  let data = await response.json(); // read response body as json
  var sortedData = [...data].sort((a, b) => b.cases - a.cases)  
  
  // Showing only top 10 country case counts
  console.log(sortedData.slice(0, 10).map(({country, cases}) => ({ country, cases})));
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```